# CSS-transitions bug

Tags: css, css-transitions

I built a slider that stores its state in sessionStorage in the browser and leverages -webkit-image-set on background images to switch between different resolution images depending on the pixel density. I tested it and made sure it was working and gracefully degrading back to IE 9, but when I implemented it in my customers site, suddenly the animated fades don't work no longer. There must be some conflicting CSS somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

A working version is implemented here:

http://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/CEtIK?editors=110

And the site I am having troubles implementing it in is here:

http://concept.rille.dk

I apply the following rule to add transitions to the elements

```
.bg-slider > * {
  [...]
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
  [...]
}
```

Note that I am using 'all' for the transition-property for debugging purposes. In the codepen I can see how it is also affecting the height of the element resulting in an animated delay in resizing the background whenever I make the browser viewport taller (I'm using js to force the element to the height of the browser), but on the live site this does not happen, pointing to the transition-property somehow not being enforced. But when I check dev tools too see if it is being overridden it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using "active" and "hidden", and it's probably the `hidden` that is not compatible with Bootstrap's class of the same name. You can test this out by removing Bootstrap and enjoying that your most excellent bg slider is working great.

**Solution:**

http://jsbin.com/danezu/1/edit

*Change the classes from `.hidden` and `.active` to something else and it works.*

Comment: Yep, I knew that it was Bootstrap even though the tag didn't say since they have a lot of utility classes that have !important on them. Annoying.